# Do we need to add "Android Enthusiasts" to the list of target sites for migration?

Tags: discussion, migration

I've just migrated a second question to Android Enthusiasts in as many days.

If you look at the [statistics](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/migrated/stats) while only 5 questions have been migrated in the last 90 days none of those have been rejected.

With increasing numbers of web applications having smart phone versions I can see this being an increasing problem where people post here rather than on the appropriate phone site.

However, adding "Android Enthusiasts" would take up the fifth (and last) migration slot so we wouldn't be able to add the Apple (for iPhone) or Windows Phone site in future should we get more questions on those topics.

I have just looked again at the [stats](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/migrated/stats) and we're getting an increasing number of Android questions being asked (I've just migrated another one). I think it's time to revisit this.

Comment: "none have been rejected" is not a strong argument with [android.se], a site with underpowered community moderation (to put it mildly).

Comment: How many of those smartphone versions are android-specific? It's not really the *web* if it doesn't work in any browser... Also, is [software  recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) already one of the migration targets?

Comment: @Nemo At the moment Software Recommendations hasn't graduated so can't appear on the list. They also have strict guidelines for questions. Most of the questions we get are of the type "how does the Android app version of this website work? "

Comment: My lowly rep makes me awkward - what are the current migration targets?

Answer (score 2):

I think migration to Android/WP/Apple site is a rare exception(per stats, questions getting migrated to Android is about a third of what gets migrated to Stack Overflow and a tenth of what gets migrated to Super User).

I don't think we need to place one in right now..

Answer (score 2):

A large number of the Android questions we get are simply because Google figures significantly in Web apps. People don't realize that Gmail questions (for example) may not belong here. We get many fewer questions that should go to [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

I say it would be worthwhile to add it now. We can always revisit in the future.

Comment: How does this match up with http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/a/230/10579 ?

Comment: @Pacerier I read that link as "if it's not about the app mechanics, it's about the webapp"